# How can I do a 301 redirect of index.html and force HTTPS?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm moving an old html site to Wordpress. The site structure looked like:

- `http://example.com/index.html`
- `http://example.com/about.html`
- `http://example.com/contact.html`

And in WordPress it now looks like:

- `https://example.com/`
- `https://example.com/about/`
- `https://example.com/contact/`

This is my `.htaccess` file

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
    
    Redirect 301 /index.html https://example.com/
    Redirect 301 /about.html https://example.com/about/
    Redirect 301 /contact.html https://example.com/contact/
    
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress
```

(Edited here to correct the error I'm getting)
This works, except `http://example.com/index.html` 301 redirects to `https://example.com/index.html`, then repeatedly 301 redirects to `https://example.com/` until it times out.

The `Redirect 301 /index.html https://example.com/` gets ignored whether I place it where it is, or above the RewriteRule line.

The other redirects that work do a 301 redirect from `http://example.com/about.html` to `https://example.com/about.html` then another 301 redirect to `https://example.com/about/` (200 OK).

How can I redirect `http://example.com/index.html` to `https://example.com`?

Comment: Did you clear your browser caches?

Comment: @AmitVerma - I did, yes.

Comment: Are you suggesting that `http://example.com/about.html` is correctly redirected? And only `/index.html` is the problem?

Comment: @MrWhite - that's correct. I used a redirect checker to test as well. It shows http://example.com/about.html redirects https://example.com/about.html then to https://example.com/about/

But http://example.com/about.html redirects to https://example.com/about.html and returns a 404.

Comment: I assume you mean `/index.html` in that second example. Did the answer below help?

Comment: @MrWhite ah, yes http://example.com/index.html redirects to https://example.com/index.html and returns 404. Answer below produced the same result. I've been wondering if the default filename in the directory may be part of the problem.

Comment: "...default filename" - That shouldn't make any difference. Are you seeing a WordPress 404 or an Apache (server generated) 404 response? Check the HTTP response headers and add these to your question. If `https://example.com/index.html` is not being redirected then it would seem the request is not reaching your server? Are you behind a front-end caching proxy, CDN, load balancer, etc?

Comment: @MrWhite - I used redirect-checker.org: http://example.com/about.html 301 redirects to https://example.com/about.html then another 301 to https://example.com/about/ (200). http://example.com/index.html 301 redirects to https://onebanquethall.com/index.html then repeatedly 301 redirects to https://onebanquethall.com/ until it times out. This also prevents https://example.com/ from loading at all (too many redirects time out error). It's not a 404, I was mistaken about that in my original post. 404 happens if I remove the 301 index.html redirect line from htaccess. No caching, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `http://example.com/index.html` 301 redirects to `https://example.com/index.html` then repeatedly 301 redirects to `https://onebanquethall.com` until it times out.

This shouldn't happen on Apache. (Are you on a LiteSpeed server?) This would be an issue if you were trying to redirect from `index.php` (since you later rewrite the request to `index.php`), but `index.html` should be OK, even it is an assigned `DirectoryIndex` document.

You might be able to resolve this by simply resetting the `DirectoryIndex` at the top of your script to explicitly remove `index.html`. For example:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

You can also add a condition to that rule so that it only redirects the initial request from the client and not any internal rewrites/subrequests that may be occurring.

For example, the complete code would look like:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

# Specific redirects
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/index\.html
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ https://example.com/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^about\.html$ https://example.com/about/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^contact\.html$ https://example.com/contact/ [L,R=301]

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS (everything else)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# BEGIN WordPress
: etc.
```

The `RewriteCond` (*condition*) directive that checks against `THE_REQUEST` server variable ensures it will only redirect direct requests from the client. `THE_REQUEST` contains the first line of the HTTP request headers and does not change if the request is rewritten. The `RewriteCond` directive only applies to the first `RewriteRule` directive that follows.

The "specific" redirects should go before the general HTTP to HTTPS in order to avoid a double redirect when requesting the old URLs over HTTP (which is what you are testing).

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. It works without the DirectoryIndex line as well so I removed that. Do you have any resources you can recommend to read up on that `THE_REQUEST` variable? And lastly, how do I check if my site is on a Litespeed server? Thank you again, I appreciate your help.

Comment: @SamTam You're welcome. "It works without the DirectoryIndex line as well" - Yes, it should. Although my query was whether `DirectoryIndex index.php` alone would resolve this issue? However, using mod_rewrite instead and positioning these directives above the HTTP to HTTPS redirect would be preferable (as written). [`THE_REQUEST` is mentioned in the Apache docs under `RewriteCond`.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

Comment: @SamTam LiteSpeed or Apache - this might be indicated in the HTTP response headers (eg. a `Server` header). Or ask your webhost. (LiteSpeed does sometimes masquerade as Apache, so it may not be obvious. Although there are various directives you can try in `.htaccess` that would indicate a LiteSpeed server.)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Redirect` with `RewriteRule` . These are two different Apache modules and work differently if intermixed. You can use the following `RewriteRule` based redirection

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^index.html$ https://example.com/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^about.html$ https://example.com/about/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^contact.html$ https://example.com/contact/ [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Make sure to clear your browser cached data before testing these updated htaccess rules.